# Gaussian fit failure in python

Tags: python, scipy

I have been trying to fit a gaussian curve to my data

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X2QL.png)

I have used the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def gaus(x, y0, a, b, c):
    return y0 + a*np.exp(-np.power(x - b, 2)/(2*np.power(c, 2)))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaus, x, y)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, c='grey', marker = 'o', label = "Measured values", s = 2)
plt.plot(x, gaus(x, *popt), c='grey', linestyle = '-')
```

And that's what I am getting:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pns7Z.png)

I have the x/y data available [here](https://pastebin.com/Vjbgd93W) in case you want to try it by yourself.

Any idea on how can I get a fit? This data is obviously gaussian shaped, so it seems weird I cannot fit a gaussian curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fit needs a decent starting point. Per the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) if you do not specify the starting point all parameters are set to 1 which is clearly not appropriate, and the fit gets stuck in some wrong local minima. Try this, where I chose the starting point by eyeballing the data

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaus, x, y, p0 = (1500,2000,20, 1))
```

you would get something like this:
[image: fit]

and the solution found by the solver is

```
popt
array([1559.13138798, 2128.64718985,   21.50092272,    0.16298357])
```

Even just getting the mean (parameter `b`) roughly right is enough for the solver to find the solution, eg try this

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaus, x, y, p0 = (1,1,20, 1))
```

you should see the same (good) result